# git push origin master Missing or invalid credentials

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

Cannot push anymore to origin master,  `git push origin master`, since a few days, I have uninstalled git and Visual Code and reinstalled it but nothing, I'v got same error :

```
Missing or invalid credentials.
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:559:14)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:433:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1168:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

I do not understand this behavior, because on my other computer everything works, and no GitHub files are corrupted.

here is my configuration : Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Need some help please !

Comment: On which os are you doing this?

Comment: is this github on premises, or a general github account? Are there proxies? Did you changed password recently? Did you do anything right before the issue like changing something in the toolchain?

Comment: In my case, after reload window in VS-Code works

Answer (score 44):

I had this error yesterday using the built in terminal in VScode. My issue was that vscode was prompting me for my github username and password at the top of VScode, and not in the terminal. I just didn't see the input field and the auth connection eventually timed out in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks, the VScode prompt for the password is really weird.

Comment: man you saved my day! :)))))))))))))))))))) it's so funny issue.

Comment: Check the following instructions to avoid this behavior in VS Code for good, so that you can even carry out git pushs and pulls using your VS Code integrated terminal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65252723/12298276. If you work with the JSON-settings file, insert the following line into it: `git.terminalAuthentication: false`, otherwise check the link for how to uncheck this option in the file -> settings.

Comment: Saved me a lot of time! Thanks!

Comment: @hexphp111 please accept this answer so that it would help others

Comment: for me. this was not the solution. still getting the error

Answer (score 4):

> Missing or invalid credentials. Error: socket hang up.

VS code always reset the git password when you close the application. When you try to push, along with this error, there is a popup box in the top asking again the git password. Enter your git password and push again.

Comment: In case you would like to avoid this behavior in VS Code, open the JSON-settings file and insert the following line into it: `git.terminalAuthentication: false`

Answer (score 3):

After Reinstallation you need to set your git credentails once again  , add VSCode permission to github account.

before pushing to a remote repository from Vscode or git after restarting your computer ,
you need to set it  first by running  following command

```html
git remote set-url origin <repo link>

git remote set-url origin https://<your github username>:<your password>@github.com/<your github username>/<your github repository name>.git
```

If this still dosen't  work reloading VSCode and running this again would help.

additionally you can run the commands in  git bash
to commit and push changes. This works for me every time

Answer (score 1):

> Just one more things I tried and it worked as previous comment How you
> can create Personal access tokens Just click on github profile setting
> => Developer settings => Personal access tokens.

```
git remote set-url origin https://<username>:<Personal_access_tokens>@github.com/<your github repository name>.git
```

After that invalid details error will not display.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution: This worked for me, use "sudo git push"**

➜ sudo git push

Username for 'https://github.com': tempName

Password for 'https://tempName@github.com':

Note: use personal access token for password.

Here you can check how to create personal access token:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens

Answer (score -1):

Finally I resolved my problem with [gitkraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) - With direct authentication.

Comment: is this a post to promote gitkraken? Your issue is with credential/network access. The GUI tool managing git has nothing to do with the answer.

Answer (score -1):

[Visual studio pop up for password][1]][1]

You can see the pop up asking for the password for your git account on the visaul studio.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Ej1.png