# git push returns Missing or invalid credentials. code: 'ECONNREFUSED', remote: Repository not found

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, econnrefused

I was able to push to 'myrepo' from my terminal without any issues until recently. Now, I am getting this -

```
Missing or invalid credentials.
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED /run/user/4714/vscode-git-b650b12c34.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/run/user/4714/vscode-git-b650b12c34.sock'
}
Missing or invalid credentials.
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED /run/user/4714/vscode-git-b650b12c34.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/run/user/4714/vscode-git-b650b12c34.sock'
}
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/me/myrepo'
```

'myrepo' is a private repo and I am a collaborator. The repository exists and my gitconfig is set properly. This error has appeared all of a sudden.

I was using integrated VS Code terminal but this same error appears when I use my desktop terminal too.

I have tried all fixes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62860280/git-push-missing-or-invalid-credentials-fatal-authentication-failed-for-http) including setting `git.terminalAuthentication: false`. However as I mentioned, I am getting this error outside VS Code too.

Can anyone please help me solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Could be the same issues as https://stackoverflow.com/q/68191392/2670892

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks a lot! The solution there works!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @greg-449 mentioned in the comments, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191392/password-authentication-is-temporarily-disabled-as-part-of-a-brownout-please-us) fixes my problem. Password-authentication is being replaced with token-based authentication.

Citing @Kusal Shrestha answer from the above link -

1. Generate a new token from git [dev settings](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).
2. Remove and readd origin locally `git remote remove origin`
3. git remote add origin `https://<token>@<git_url>.git`
4. pull once: `git pull https://<token>@<git_url>.git`

Comment: this worked for me but just with classic tokens, with fine-grained tokens it did not work in my end